# Запись данных с точкой в postgresql psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Есть код который в зависимости от входящих в модуль типов данных записывает разные промежутки
Но есть проблема, которая возникае при записи названий файлов ибо они в себе имеют такие значения как ".",
Пример записанного файла:

```
__Release_Notes/Q3.2/Poy/3154__Data_1
```

Но в файле с названием:

```
__Release_Notes/Q3.1/C394
```

Он жалуется на

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ".1"
LINE 4: ...                               (__Release_Notes/Q3.1/
```

Сам код выглядит так

```
# SQL-запрос для создания новой таблицы
def create_table(time, cursor, count_time):
    create_table_query = f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {time}
                              (
                              metada TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                              {count_time}   INT 
                              ); '''
    cursor.execute(create_table_query)

    # Выполнение команды: это создает новую таблицу


def inster_into_table_one_day(cursor, Changedata, time):
     #dfirst need del 
    ID = 1
    for ticket, day in Changedata.items():
        if ticket == 'Merge_or_Fix':
            continue
        ID += 1
        insert_table_query = f'''INSERT INTO {time}
                                  (metada, one_day)
                                  VALUES
                                  ('{ticket}', {day})
                                   ; '''
        cursor.execute(insert_table_query)
```

Comment: попробуйте f-строки заменить на placeholders, они должны будут экранироваться, чтобы избегать таких ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо!, попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением является обособление данных в `'` или `"` при этом может появится ошибка типа данных, так что я поменял все на `text`